# What is the point of WPF data binding? Implementing INotifyPropertyChange versus manual GUI updating

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I recently made a very simple app in WPF that simply reads data from a few TextBoxes and updates records in an SQL Server database. I also put back and forward buttons to allow the user to scroll through the available records. Everytime the user clicks Next on the app, the UI gets updated with the values from the new record through a method I called updateControls(), which looks like this:

```
private void updateControls()
    {
        IQueryable<Comment> query = from t in container.Comment
                                    where t.Id == browseIndex
                                    select t;
        if (query.Count<Comment>() > 0)
        {
            currentComment = query.First<Comment>();
            txtID.Text = currentThought.Id.ToString();
            txtComment.Text = currentComment.thought;
            txtDate.DisplayDate = currentComment.date;
            txtDate.Text = currentComment.date.ToString();

        }
    }
```

This is simple, and it works like a charm. But I recently discovered the world of data-binding, where you can supposedly eliminate all this boilerplate code of manually updating controls and have them update themselves whenever the model changes.

After much experimentation and reading through various tutorials, I find that, for this to work, my data object must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, which means need to use explicit setters on the properties I wish to update on my UI, like this:

```
public class Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged {
   private string comment;
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public string Comment { get { return this.comment;}
   set {
      this.comment = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Comment");
   }

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null ) this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
   }

}
```

This is a lot more code than simply manually updating my UI with the data I want. Also, since this class is part of an Entity Model, the INotifyPropertyChanged interface has to be implemented in a class apart from the model classes, since model classes get regenerated when the model is updated. Which leads me to my question: why ever would I want to use data-binding in a real world application when it is much simpler to simply update my UI manually? Or is there an alternative way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVVM pattern dissociates the GUI logic from the core logic.

- You can have the same model for several totally different controls and on the other way have one complex control leverage on several totally different models (the ViewModel is just the glue).
- If you work on a team, you may have one guy working on the GUI part and another one dedicated to databases.
- The database (model) is no more enslaved by the way you show the data, as long as the ViewModel notifies its changes, it'll be up to the View to decide to catch it or not (with a simple binding)
- when you work with datatemplate, everything will make a lot more sense because it'll be VERY easy to render complex

There are many reasons why this pattern is great, there are plenty of articles on internet

Comment: While I understand the benefits of having a view model, I find it cumbersome to need to implement INotifyPropertyChange and define explicit setters and getters for every single field in the model, just so the UI can "update itself". Does the .NET framework provide a simpler way to do this or are stuck with INotifyPropertyChange for good?

Comment: The model may have several fields which don't need events. You implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` _only_ on the fields you want. It makes the separation clearer and the total number for events smaller while adding easy model awareness to the GUI